# Can the MCP2221 send serial data through a USB serial link?

Tags: microcontroller, usb-device, programmer

I am using a MCP2221A to program an ATMEGA1284p through the USART/UART lines(converting USB signals from the computer into a programming signal the MCU can read). However, given that I can *send* serial data from the computer, to the USB/USART bridge, then to the MCU, can I do the opposite(sending data from the MCU to the computer)?

I have looked through the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP2221A-Data-Sheet-20005565E.pdf) for the MCP2221A, and all that sticks out to me is the following passages:

> Implements USB Protocol Composite Device: - Communication Device Class (CDC) for USB-to-UART conversion

from the first page, and:

> The MCP2221A enumerates as a composite USB device after POR. The device enumerates as both a Human Interface Device (HID) for I2C, GPIO control, and as CDC for the USB-to-UART converter.

as well as

> The MCP2221A has a built-in USB 2.0 full-speed transceiver internally connected to the USB module.

Since I am using USART communication, the datasheet states the chip identifies itself as a CDC(communication device class) USB device, also mentioning that it contains an internal USB *transceiver*. Does this mean that serial data can be sent back to the computer and read via a serial port(e.g. from the Arduino IDE)? The datasheet does not state much about sending data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few paragraphs into the first page ("features") I find this:

> • 448-Byte Buffer to Handle Data Throughput at Any Supported UART Baud
> Rate:
>
> - 64-byte transmit
> - 384-byte receive

A few lines down from there:

> - Supports Baud Rates: 300-460800
> - UART UTx and URx Pins Only

Keep searching on "receive" and you will keep finding things like this.
Short of hooking one up to be sure, I'm pretty confident this will do what you want.  The CDC class certainly handles send and receive, and the part has hardware for I/O, so the only way it wouldn't work is if the firmware left out that capability.

Comment: Thanks. This the exact answer I was looking for, I thought the buffer was between the MCP2221 and the MCU, not straight through to the USB link.